# How do i call this code using jsoup login

Tags: java, android, jsoup

How do I call this code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Connection.Response loginForm = Jsoup.connect("http://deeproute.com/deeproute/default.asp")
            .method(Connection.Method.GET)
            .execute();

    Document document = Jsoup.connect("http://deeproute.com/deeproute/default.asp")
            .data("cookieexists", "false")
            .data("name", "username")
            .data("password", "pass")
            .data("subbera", "Login")
            .cookies(loginForm.cookies())
            .post();

}
```

I want to know how to call this code  I have added this to my `MainActivity` and now I want to know how to call it. I am learning how to make a `post` using `jsoup`.

Comment: You can't use this code directly in `MainActivity` - It has a long execution time so it will block the UI for long time, and Android does not allow that. Put that code in an `AsyncTask` and call the task from your main. Try to google it, you'll find lots of stuff.

Comment: @TDG you should post your comment as an answer.

Comment: @alkis Do you think so? It's not answering directly the question, it's just gives a direction?

Comment: I believe it answers it. You pointed out the biggest issue. That this code can't be in MainActivity but in AsyncTask instead. If you believe that it would be more complete with some code, you can provide the simplest version of (the simplest code out there using AsyncTask).

Answer (score 1):

You can't use this code directly in `MainActivity` - It has a long execution time so it will block the UI which is not allowedby Android. Put that code in an `AsyncTask` and call the task from your main. You can use it like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //Do some stuff here
    new ConnectToInternet().execute();  //And call your task
}

private class ConnectToInternet extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        //place here your code for accessing the web
        return YOUR_ANSWER_AS_STRING  //or modify the return type
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
       //This method receives your String result of
       //doInBackground so you can process it here.
    }
```

You can read more about it [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).